# React Native graphql query with relay: fetched data not received

Tags: react-native, graphql, relayjs, relay

I have the following query:

```
query {
  viewer{
    place(id: "1a4871311fe990d6d94cf1eed9fd65008856e118b790e7dcf728d86bc3aef7ec"){
      name
    }
  }
}
```

which of course works correctly on GraphiQL. I would like to use this query in a Relay container so I've created a RootContainer:

```
<RootContainer
  Component={PlaceDetailsComponent}
  route={new PlaceDetailsRoute({placeID: this.props.id})}
  renderFetched={(data) => {
    console.log('data: ', data);
    return (
      <PlaceDetailsComponent {...this.props} {...data}/>
    )
  } }
  renderLoading={() => <ProgressBar visible={true} />}/>
```

which successfully fetches the data but all I can see on console is this:

```
data:  { placeID: '1a4871311fe990d6d94cf1eed9fd65008856e118b790e7dcf728d86bc3aef7ec',
  viewer: 
   { __dataID__: 'Vmlld2VyLXs6aWQ9PiJ2aWV3ZXIifQ==',
     __fragments__: { '1::client': [ {} ] } } }
```

So I checked out what's actually sent to server and what's received and all seems right to me:

[image]

Here is my route:

```
import Relay, { 
  Route
} from 'react-relay';

class PlaceDetailsRoute extends Route {
  static queries = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      query {
        viewer 
      }
      `
  }
  static routeName = 'PlaceDetailsRoute'
}

export default PlaceDetailsRoute;
```

and here is my fragment:

```
Relay.createContainer(PlaceDetailsContainer, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer  {
        place(id: "1a4871311fe990d6d94cf1eed9fd65008856e118b790e7dcf728d86bc3aef7ec") {
          name,
        }
      }
      `
  }
});
```

Any suggestions what should I change? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What tool do use the debug the graphql query from react-native(in ref to the pic you attached)? Need something like that desperately. Thanks.

Comment: @user3740387 - that's Charles, you can download it here: https://www.charlesproxy.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually expected behavior. The [Relay documentation of `renderFetched`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-root-container.html#renderfetched) has a note:

> Even though we have access to the `data` object in `renderFetched`, the actual data is intentionally opaque. This prevents the `renderFetched` from creating an implicit dependency on the fragments declared by `Component`.

Hope this clears up your confusion.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!